# Loading a Dataframe that took 2 minutes on Spark-shell is taking forever in Zeppelin

Tags: emr, amazon-emr

Loading a Dataframe that took 2 minutes on Spark-shell is taking forever in Zeppelin, running a single node Master, using emr-5.0.0

Comment: Please paste a snippet of your application code.

Answer (score 0):

While Spark-Shell was able to run my query on previous edition hardware (m1-medium), Zeppelin needed memory optimized hardware (r3.2xlarge), to virtually run the same query, on the same data!

Comment: this detail should be part of the original question's supporting information above.

Answer (score 0):

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-zeppelin-users/201505.mbox/%3CCAD7JkQGRTbk4k6_d=wJrfCPEmXSJMpeN=jZOuxMVdUcH-RfO1w@mail.gmail.com%3E

Apparently there is a difference in how the tasks are created and run when running queries between various contexts. If you paste your code, maybe we can see the difference.

I can tell you that when you're running a spark shell, vs a spark-submit, there are slight differences in how the contexts are setup.